# Python list problem : want to get the data only and remove the title of the field

Tags: python

I am getting this kind of list from mongodb in python.
***list1 = [{'a':'1'},{'a':'2'}]***
I wanted to get the values of the data from this list.
when i tried ***print(a[0])*** this gave me ***{'a':'1'}***
I just wanted to get the numerical values of this list to perform other maths operations on it. but i am unable to get the numerical values.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print(int(list1[0]["a"]))`

Answer (score 3):

you have to iterate over list element and get the vlaue from the dictionary.

eg

```
new_list1 = list(map(lambda x:x['a'], list1))
```

or using list comprehension, as suggested by @schwobaseggl

```
new_list1 = [i.get('a', None) for i in list1]
```

Comment: if this solution help you fully, then you can accept this one as correct solution

Answer (score 0):

```
[v for d in list1 for (k,v) in d.items() ]
```

Output

```
['1', '2']
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I solved the problem with your help :)